# Websphere Database login module?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I'd need to know if it's possible to secure the WAS 8 console (and generally speaking Java EE applications running on it) with a Database Login module, so that Users and Groups are stored on the DB. As far as I can see, the only options available in the Security Wizard are local OS, File based security, Standalone LDAP or Federated LDAP....

Answer (score 2):

There is another option - custom. With this option you have to provide a Java class which will perform the function of connecting from WebSphere to the database. A sample class is provided so that you can see what needs to be done and there is [documentation in the Information Center](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tsec_tdaman.html).